# How to add the installation prefix of "MITK"

Tags: build, cmake, mitk

In Windows 7 x64, VisualStudio 2010, I need to know how to set Cmake path.

There is an error message which says

```
Add the installation prefix of "MITK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "MITK_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
```

Do you have any idea on how to add the installation prefix of "MITK"?

Answer (score 0):

To append something to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH You can use something like this ([1]):

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/some-path/")
```

Setting some variable can also be done from console while invoking CMake. For example like this ([2]) :

```
cmake -DMITK_DIR:STRING="C:/some-path" ..
```

Or directly in the CMakeLists.txt ([3]):

```
set(MITK_DIR "C:/some-path")
```

[1] http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/list.html

[2] [Passing the argument to CMAKE via command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12896988/1150918)

[3] http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html