# How to pass a varible to a cmake script

Tags: c++, cmake, configuration

I am trying to pass a variable to a cmake script but it I am obviously not doing it correctly. I am trying to build a chrono project by following the tutorial. Tutorial I am following is here:

https://api.projectchrono.org/tutorial_install_project.html

the CMakeLists.txt is modified below to:

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------
# 
# Example of CMake configuration file to build an external 
# project depending on Chrono and on optional Chrono modules.
# 
# This minimal sample project can be used as a template for a
# user project.  Modify sections 1, 2, and 3 below as appropriate.
# 
#--------------------------------------------------------------
 

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# === 1 === 
# Modify the project name if you want: 
#--------------------------------------------------------------

project(my_project)

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# === 2 ===
# Find the Chrono package and any REQUIRED or OPTIONAL modules
# by invoking the find_package function in CONFIG mode:
find_package(Chrono
             COMPONENTS Irrlicht
             CONFIG)

# The following Chrono modules can be requested (their names
# are case insensitive): Cascade, Cosimulation, FEA, Irrlicht,
# Matlab, Parallel, Postprocess, Python, Vehicle.
# 
# Note that you will have to set the variable Chrono_DIR to 
# specify the location of the ChronoConfig.cmake script, if
# it is not in its default install location.
# Chrono_DIR can be either a Chrono build tree or a Chrono install tree.
# 
# The following variables are set and can be used further down:
# CHRONO_FOUND
#   set to true if Chrono and all required components were found
# CHRONO_C_FLAGS
# CHRONO_CXX_FLAGS
#   C and C++ compilation flags
# CHRONO_INCLUDE_DIRS
#   additional paths for included headers
# CHRONO_LIBRARIES
#   list of required libraries (with full path)
# CHRONO_LINKER_FLAGS
#   additional linker flags
# CHRONO_DLLS
#   list of all DLL dependencies (with full path)
# CHRONO_DATA_DIR
#   path to the Chrono data make_directory
# 
# In addition, for each requested component [COMPONENT], the
# following variable is set to true (ON) or false (OFF):
# CHRONO_[COMPONENT]_FOUND
# 
# In this example, we only request the Irrlicht module (required)
#--------------------------------------------------------------
#Chrono_DIR = "/home/richard/chrono_build/lib"

LIST(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/../Chrono/lib")
find_package(Chrono
             COMPONENTS Irrlicht
             CONFIG)

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Return now if Chrono or a required component was not found.
#--------------------------------------------------------------

if (NOT Chrono_FOUND)
  message("Could not find Chrono or one of its required modules")
  return()
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Enable creation of "application bundles" on MacOSX.
#--------------------------------------------------------------

# This is necessary for any Irrlicht-based project (like the example here).
# For OpenGL-based or non-graphics projects, this is optional and the block
# below can be removed (or else explcitly set CMAKE_MACOSX_BUNDLE to 'OFF').
#
# If creating application bundles, the build output will be named 'myexe.app'.
# Use the convenience script 'run_app.sh' available under 'contrib/appbundle-macosx/'
# to run:
#     start_demo.sh myexe.app

if(APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_MACOSX_BUNDLE ON)
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Add path to Chrono headers and to headers of all dependencies
# of the requested modules.
#--------------------------------------------------------------

include_directories(${CHRONO_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Fix for VS 2017 15.8 and newer to handle alignment specification with Eigen
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows")
  if(MSVC AND ${MSVC_VERSION} GREATER_EQUAL 1915)
    add_definitions( "-D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE" )
  endif()
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Tweaks to disable some warnings with MSVC
#--------------------------------------------------------------
if(MSVC)
    add_definitions("-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE")  # avoids deprecation warnings
    add_definitions("-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE")  # avoids deprecation warnings
    add_definitions( "-DNOMINMAX" )                # do not use MSVC's min/max macros
    set(EXTRA_COMPILE_FLAGS "/wd4275")             # disable warnings triggered by Irrlicht
else()
    set(EXTRA_COMPILE_FLAGS "")
endif()

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# === 3 ===
# Add the executable from your project and specify all C++ 
# files in your project. 
#--------------------------------------------------------------

add_executable(myexe my_example.cpp)

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Set properties for your executable target
# 
# Note that here we define a macro CHRONO_DATA_DIR which will
# contain the path to the Chrono data directory, either in its
# source tree (if using a build version of Chrono), or in its
# install tree (if using an installed version of Chrono).
#--------------------------------------------------------------

set_target_properties(myexe PROPERTIES 
        COMPILE_FLAGS "${CHRONO_CXX_FLAGS} ${EXTRA_COMPILE_FLAGS}"
        COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "CHRONO_DATA_DIR=\"${CHRONO_DATA_DIR}\""
        LINK_FLAGS "${CHRONO_LINKER_FLAGS}")

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Link to Chrono libraries and dependency libraries
#--------------------------------------------------------------

target_link_libraries(myexe ${CHRONO_LIBRARIES})

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# === 4 (OPTIONAL) ===
# 
# Optionally, add a custom command for copying all Chrono and
# dependency DLLs to the appropriate binary output folder.
# This function has effect only on Windows.
# 
# Note that you must first set EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH
# (this can simply be ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}, like in this example)
#--------------------------------------------------------------

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
add_DLL_copy_command("${CHRONO_DLLS}")
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and am trying to setup the build using cmake. The command I am using is:

```
cmake -S template_project/ -B build -Chrono_DIR:STRING=/home/richard/chrono_build/lib
```

Error I get is:

```
home/richard/chrono_build/lib
loading initial cache file hrono_DIR:STRING=/home/richard/chrono_build/lib
CMake Error: Error processing file: /home/richard/Chrono_workspace/hrono_DIR:STRING=/home/richard/chrono_build/lib
-- Could NOT find Chrono (missing: Chrono_DIR)
-- Could NOT find Chrono (missing: Chrono_DIR)
Could not find Chrono or one of its required modules
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/richard/Chrono_workspace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Obviously this is not to correct way of setting "Chrono_Dir" as I am getting errors. How do I pass that info along when using the CMake command, or do I need to add it to the cmakelists.txt file? I know this is a newbie question, but I am stuck and would like some help. I tried following this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896988/passing-the-argument-to-cmake-via-command-prompt), but I obviously don't get what is going on.

EDIT:

I trying the comments/answer below did this:

```
cmake -S template_project/ -B build -DChrono_DIR=/home/richard/chrono_build/lib
```

and now the output is:

```
-- Could NOT find Chrono (missing: Chrono_DIR)
-- Could NOT find Chrono (missing: Chrono_DIR)
Could not find Chrono or one of its required modules
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/richard/Chrono_workspace/build
```

Comment: You forgot -D before variable name. Try 
cmake -S template_project/ -B build --DChrono_DIR:STRING=/home/richard/chrono_build/lib

Comment: try -DChrono_DIR instead -Chrono_DIR

Comment: @AliRazmkhah Got a bit further, but still not quite working updated my question above. Chrono_DIR is still missing

Comment: From the description: "Chrono_DIR can be either a Chrono build tree or a Chrono install tree.". So, whether the value (`/home/richard/chrono_build/lib`) you have specified for `Chrono_DIR` variable is the **build tree** or the **install tree**? According to the directories naming, it smells like build tree is `/home/richard/chrono_build` and you set `Chrono_DIR` to its `lib/` **subdirectory**, which contradicts to the description.

Comment: @Tsyvarev did as you suggested. Still getting the same output. The documentation also states 'you will have to set the variable Chrono_DIR to specify the location of the ChronoConfig.cmake script, if it is not in its default install location.' There is no ChronoConfig.cmake script in the my Chrono Build.. Weird. Will have to do some more looking online I guess.

Comment: Chonro document is for windows! if you search how install/build chrono in ubuntu may be you find right solution!

Comment: @AliRazmkhah That it is. Will have to do some more searching as you suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try it:

```
cmake -S template_project/ -B build -DChrono_DIR=/home/richard/chrono_build/lib
```

> cmake -D : Create or update a CMake CACHE entry.

And then you can access it in CMakeList.txt like this:

```
message("Chrono_DIR=" ${Chrono_DIR})
```

Comment: Got a bit further, but still not quite working updated my question above. Chrono_DIR is still missing

Comment: @Dick This did solve your question. The fact that you had other issues with your setup is not really relevant. Updating the question with the next problem you ran into is not the way to deal with this. Mark as accepted, and write a new question for the next problem. One question per question.  Have a look in the [help] for more info about the rules and guidelines for SO.

Comment: @Dick  you can access it in CMakeList.txt like this: message("Chrono_DIR=" ${Chrono_DIR})