# Automatically copy dlls to output directory CPP Using Poco

Tags: c++, cmake, poco

CMakeLists - it should automatically copy dlls of poco to output directory where right to the exe file in CPP

Comment: [`file(<COPY|INSTALL>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#copy)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65981227/how-to-pass-a-varible-to-a-cmake-script                                                                                                                                           The above link appropriately working ,change the name DChrono_DIR to Dyourname and access in CmakeLists.txt.