# PocoCryptod.lib & PocoNetSSLd.lib libraries not built during cmake

Tags: c++, poco, poco-libraries

I am trying to install POCO so I can run api requests.  2 libraries are never installed when I follow the directions on the poco site.  These libraries are:

PocoCryptod.lib
PocoNetSSLd.lib

When I run

```
cmake - H/path/to/poco -B/path/to/poco-build
```

I get the following error:

```
--Could not find OpenSSl, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Where do I set the OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR?

I'm confused.  Any help?

Comment: You should not have to change the CMakeLists.txt for the poco library.

Comment: ***Where do I set the OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR?***  Most likely using CMake-GUI or on the command line at the configure stage or even add an environment variable in your shell before you configure. Or you could use a CMakePresets file: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html)

Comment: I took a look at the CMakeLists.txt file and I agree no change needs to be made there.  I have not had a chance to look at the cmake-gui, I'll take a look later on tonight and will let you know the answer.  As far as I can tell, this poco stuff has no good documentation and i couldn't find anyplace online with complete instructions for this.

Comment: This may also help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896988/passing-an-argument-to-cmake-via-command-prompt/12899005#12899005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896988/passing-an-argument-to-cmake-via-command-prompt/12899005#12899005)

Comment: And the first post here has an example: [https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/pull/8995](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/pull/8995)

Comment: Ok, I fixed that problem, but when I build the poco libraries, those two libraries (PocoCryptod.lib & PocoNetSSLd.lib) are still not being built.  For documentation purposes, I created a new windows enviornment variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR and set it to the directory where the libcrypto.lib file was located, which was in [POCO-BASE}\openssl\build\win64\bin\release   That did the trick.  When I run cmake, I no longer run into that error but the CRYPTO lib and NetSSL_OpenSSL components are not being built.  Any idea what I have to do have those libraries built?

Comment: Something wierd is happening.  I deleted the poco-build folder and started the build from scratch.  I ran into another error: 'Could Not find OPENSSL, try to set the path to OpenSsl root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR(missing:OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR).  I ran the first cmake command 3 times.  To fix this, I moved the include folder to the same path as the OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR and started the cmake from scratch again.  It found openssl and did build the crypto and netssl_openssl components.  I will continue with the build and will report back what happens.

Comment: The build completes but the libraries I need (PocoCryptod.lib & PocoNetSSLd.lib) are not built.  I checked the console and found the following errors: 1. 'Link : fatal error lnk1104: cannot open file 'libcryptod.lib' [[Poco-build]\crypto\Crypto.vcxproj ]. 2. A number of Exgternal OpenSSL defined but internal headers used - possible mismatch! errors.  I didn't see naything related to crypto or netssl_openssl, I assume its because they are depenendent on openssl which err'd out.  Any idea's as to what's going on?

Comment: Changing the OPEN_SSL_ROOT_DIR to [poco-base]\openssl\build\win64\bin\debug and moving the include folder to that location did the trick.  I started the build from scratch and the PocoCryptod.lib built.  However the PocoNetSSLd.lib file is giving me problems.  There are a number of errors in the build of the type: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file ' Poco/Net/FileName.h' No such file or directory [[poco-build]\NetSSL_OpenSSL\NetSSL.vcxproj]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  Go to windows environment variables and create a new variable `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR`. Set it to `poco-unzipped-files-location]\openssl\build\win64\bin\debug`.  Also move the include directory to this location.  My problem with the missing header files was that I had removed them during a previous try.  It shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: To support both the Release and Debug configurations `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` probably should be `poco-unzipped-files-location]\openssl\build` I am not 100% sure I would have to test or examine the finder.

Comment: I tried that location and it wasn't picking everything up.  It wasn't until I put the OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR to the debug/release folder that it worked fine. Idk why it was like that.